# How to avoid header or even other containers from messing up when zoomed in/out?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a Bootstrap-like header with navigations but I just found out that when I zoomed out the window, the contents inside the header are messing up and the header also minimizes instead of staying on the same size. I already used **vh** unit on the header so that it will only stay on the same size with any screen device's size but it doesn't work. I only want the content to become smaller as it gets zoomed out but not the header just like on the Bootstrap Themes I saw, how can this be achieved without using Bootstrap?
Here's the **SCREENSHOT IMAGE** of my code:

[image]

And here's what I want to [ACHIEVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFKHc.png): This was zoomed out but only the contents became small, not the header.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dental Services</title>
        <meta name="project" content="Dental Services">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="master-header">
            <nav class="nav-bar">
                <div class="nav-container">
                    <div class="brand-container">
                        <span class="brand-name">Dental Services</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav-links">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Services</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">About</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sign In</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1 class="motto">We care about</br> your teeth</h1>

                    <form class="login-form">
                        <p class="form-title">Get started for free</p>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" />
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" />
                        <button class="bnt-submit">Get Started</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    font: 1rem Arial;
    background: #AAA;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    margin: 25px 0; padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #BBB; border-radius: 3px;
    font: 1em Arial;
    color: #555;
    background: #FFF;
    transition: box-shadow 100ms linear;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
button {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    border: 0; border-radius: 4px;
    font: 1em Arial;
    color: #FFF;
    background: Mediumseagreen;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: background 100ms linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
    background: Seagreen;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: Steelblue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px Lightsteelblue;
}
.master-header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/header_img.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.nav-bar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 94%;
    margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 15px;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.brand-container {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.brand-name {
    position: relative;
    color: #DDD;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.nav-links {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav-links li {
    font: 1em Arial;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav-links li a {
    color: #DDD;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 100ms linear;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.nav-links li a:hover {
    color: #AAA;
}
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.motto {
    font: 5em Arial;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.login-form {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    background: #FFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
.form-title {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
    font: 1.5em Arial;
    color: #666;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: when i zoom out on this bootsrap default template, the navigation doesnt stay the same size like you claim https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/starter-template/

Comment: use container fluids instead of container because containers have max-width:1170px and container-fluid will stretch your content to fit the screen .

Comment: @johnSmith Try this one and you'll understand.
https://www.getreplacer.com/template-1.html

Comment: The only difference is all of the width

Comment: @SumitKumar No, I didn't use Bootstrap on my code. It's just pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: @johnSmith I added a link on my comment.

Comment: So if you are using the main container with the fixed with try to make them 100% width and inner containers with percentage width as well

Comment: @RockyTac-an i guess you need to seperate your "content " from the `<header>` the element with the background-image needs to be width 100% and the actual-content need max-width: x and margin left and right auto

Comment: yeah @johnSmith you are right the navbar will be 100%; outer content div with background image will be 100%; and inner content div will be with a max-width and margin:auto;

Comment: @johnSmith Nah, it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I fixed it with one CSS property: **background-size: cover;**
I thought the header itself was becoming smaller as it gets zoomed out. But I found out that only the background image became smaller and I fixed it myself when I tried **background-size: cover;**.